# Is King Joffrey not actually Robert's Son?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Joffrey came across as a bit of a little **** in Seasons 1 and 2, but in Season 3 (especially the end of The Climb) we see that he is utterly, utterly insane.

Could the source of this madness be that he is actually be born of incest between Jaime and Cersei? How could anyone know?

Comment: The title of this question is very different from the actual question.  Also, if you've watched the show, you have all the information anyone else does (excluding possible spoilers from the text).  Also, does incest lead to homicidal mania?

Comment: Are you asking about Joffreys parents or Joffrey's insanity?

Comment: I am totally clueless about how you may have missed that one. He's probably not insane, by the way, just a nasty little spoiled brat.

Comment: @mh01 - I wouldn't be so sure. It's been established in the books that Targaryen incest has produced it's fair share of crazy Targs... Now add the fact that Mad King Aerys lusted after Jaime and Cersie's mother... I'll leave that to simmer for a while :P

Answer (score 7):

[Joffrey Baratheon's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joffrey_Baratheon#Joffrey_Baratheon) biological parents are

> Jaime and Cersei Lannister